# iPad detailItem Access

Tags: ipad

In my AppDelegate I setup my splitview using the xcode4 template.  The code is below.  My question is, how do I access the detailItem property from my MasterViewControll's didSelectRowAtIndexPath method?  The new splitview template changed the structure of the starter code and the detailViewController is no longer setup as an IBOutlet.

AppDelegate.m

```
    masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];        
    UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

    self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController, nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
```

MasterViewController.m
I would like to do something like this:

```
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = some object;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectsAtIndex:1] setDetailItem:someObject];`.

Comment: I already tried that and I get the error: ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setDetailItem:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6058380'

Comment: Use `[[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectsAtIndex:1] rootViewController] setDetailItem:someObject];` instead and you should read something about UINavigation controller and view controllers in general.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have read about UINavigation and view controllers in general, but was not able to see the solution.  Regarding your solution, using rootViewController did not work, but visibleViewController does. I'm diving into the documentation to understand it better.  Thanks again.

Comment: Above formula is not working is shows the warning and app is going to crash

Comment: Of course, because `setDetailItem` is a custom method of RickR's detail view controller.